# must call a designated initializer of the superclass NSManagedObject - in swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I get the compiler message: must call a designated initializer of the superclass NSManagedObject
  (in swift)

```
//-------------------------------------
class abc : NSManagedObject {
    init(x:String, y:String){
        super.init()      // <<====== here!!
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
//-------------------------------------
```

the var(s) are declared in the 
extension xxxx {
    ....
}
How to initialize this superclass?

Answer (score 8):

The designated initialiser is

```
init(entity entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?)
```

and that is the super `init` function you must call.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262) I would do it like this this:

```
class abc : NSManagedObject {
    init(x:String, y:String , entity: NSEntityDescription, context: NSManagedObjectContext?){
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
```